# JS: How to pass selected data to the next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

My users have a sharepoint list where they can add items. Sometimes they have to create very similar items. So I would like to add a column to the list where is a button or make one of the column into a link. If this pressed:

1. The item's data from the button/link's row is stored.
2. Go to the new item creation page.
3. Autofill all inputfiels with the stored data.

This way the user just have to modify few fields and can finish a new item creation much faster. Simply accessing the display page from the new item page is not enough because we need to know at least the item's ID to be able to select the right item.

What would be the best approach? Thanks you very much for any idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the localstorage api, accessible from the window object.

Once you have the values in scope, set them in localStorage, you'll then be able to access that value on a new page, after a refresh, etc.

Example:

```
//I'm using JSON.stringify here because it will allow you to store objects, not just primitive values such as Number, String, Boolean.
window.localStorage.setItem(“key”, JSON.stringify({“Foo”:”bar”});
```

Then look it up on your new page

```
var item = window.localStorage.getItem(“key”);

//We need to parse the JSON we stringified, otherwise you'll end up with a string value.
console.log(JSON.parse(item));
```

This would log:

```
{"Foo": "bar"}
```

You're then free to populate any form fields with the fields retrieved from the value we fetched from localStorage.

You can then clean up localStorage at a logic point in your script.

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("key");
```

Now it's clear.

```
//This will now log undefined.
console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("key"));
```

Having JSON.stringify and JSON.parse calls in your code can easily result in it becoming harder to read. I'd advise you create or use a third-party service for interacting with it.

A simple example is below, this could be improved and is by no means meant as a complete, all bells and whistles localstorage wrapper.

```
//Create a **single** global App object, you can access the service
//hereon out with 'window.App'. 
var App = (window.App || (window.App = {}));

//Make a little service for interacting with local storage

App.Storage = {

    //Wrap the call to JSON.parse inside the service's get function
    getItem: function (key) {
         return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
    },

    //Wrap the call to JSON.stringify in the service's set function
    setItem: function (key, value) {
         return window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    },

    //Not really neccesary as no JSON calls are used here
    //Worth adding for completeness sakes though.
    removeItem: function (key) {
        return window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
    }
};
```

If you use a service like that, then your code then becomes a lot nicer to read.

Example:

```
var foo = { "Foo": "bar" };

//No JSON.stringify call :)
window.App.Storage.setItem("key", foo);

//Logs the object with no JSON.parse call directly in your business logic.
console.log(window.App.Storage.getItem("key"));

//Remove the item...
window.App.Storage.removeItem("key");

//Will now log 'undefined'
console.log(window.App.Storage.getItem("key"));
```

Note, in the browser 'window' is implied, so you could replace 'window.App' above with 'App'.

You could also save javascript some work by caching the Storage service object in local scope.

Example:

```
var Storage = App.Storage;

Storage.getItem();
Storage.setItem();
Storage.removeItem();
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for the detailed instructions, it worked! It was easy to understand even if this was my first try!

Comment: No problem, happy coding!